# src/main/resources not added in war class path

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, tomcat8

I have developed a web + maven project. All development is completed. Now I am trying to deploy on production. I am encountering a problem that no content from `src/main/resources` is added in my `ProjectName.war/WEB-INF/classes/` folder. Check the screenshot

[image: Incident Management]

Like `hibernate.cfg.xml` is not there and also other files/folders are not in class path (`ProjectName.war/WEB-INF/classes/`). Am I missing any plugin ? I thought that `src/main/resources`'s content should be added automatically according to [this link](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html).

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>IncidentManagement</groupId>
    <artifactId>IncidentManagement</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src.main.java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
        <mojarra.version>2.2.12</mojarra.version>
        <primefaces.version>5.3</primefaces.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.3</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ORACLE database driver -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>  -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mojarra JSF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${mojarra.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${mojarra.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- PrimeFaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Excel and CSV -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PDF -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
           <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
           <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Primefaces Theme -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces.extensions/all-themes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your folder structure is wrong, it should be `src/main/java` or `src/test/java`.. and what you have is with `src.main.java`. Please re-create the maven project from start use the command below

[image]

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=IncidentManagement
   -DartifactId=IncidentManagement
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart
   -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Comment: Well that is bit late. I have to fix it now, I cannot test all again. Is there any other way (by editing `pom.xml`) ?

Comment: @Junaid try to fix the folder structure atleast src/main/java is what you need to have.

Comment: Fix this current project or make a new one?

Comment: @Junaid fix this one. src.main.java is wrong, it should be src/main/java

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

1. create new folders with name src/main/java, src/main/resources src/test/java  src/test/resources  and src/main/webapp
2. move all your class/file in their respective folder after that, delete the wrongs folder
3. right click on the folder src/main/java etc, and select -->Build Path -->Use as Source Folder.
4. Create the META-INF folder in src/main/reources where you can put file like MANIFEST.MF or persistence.xml.
5. Create two folder in src/main/webapp : META-INF and WEB-INF ; on META-INF you can put file like MANIFEST.MF, in WEB-INF you can put file like web.xml

Answer (score 0):

First check resources is in build path in your IDE .If yes then remove  `maven-war-plugin` from your pom and try again to build and deploy . It may work .